# Proof by Cases involving divisibility

Tags: divisibility, proof-explanation

To prove that if $n$ is odd, then $8 \mid n^2−1$, observe that as $n$ is odd either $n = 4k+1$ for some integer $k$ or $n=4k+3$ for some integer $k$. In the first case $n^2 -1=8(2k^2+k)$ and in the second case $n^2-1 = 8(2k^2 + 3k + 1)$.

Given an odd integer $a$, establish that $a^2 +(a+2)^2 +(a+4)^2 + 1$ is divisible by $12$. Solve by consideration of six cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,f(n\!+\!2)-f(n) = (a\!+\!6)^2\!-a^2 = \color{#c00}{12}(n\!+\!3),\ $ so $\ {\rm mod}\ \color{#c00}{12}\!:\ f(n\!+\!2)\equiv f(n)\ $ therefore by induction $\ 0\equiv f(1)\equiv f(3)\equiv f(5)\equiv \cdots$

Comment: And similarly for negative odds $\,f(1)\equiv f(-1)\equiv f(-3)\equiv \cdots\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We don't really need to handle cases separately as

$$(2m+1)^2=8\cdot\dfrac{m(m+1)}2+1$$

Now, $$(a-2)^2+a^2+(a+2)^2+1=3a^2+9=3(a^2-1)+12$$

Comment: this might be a stupid question but why did you include (a-2)^2 and removed the (a+4)^2 . I understand that (a-2)^2 is the number before a^2

Comment: @Flow, Both are valid expression of sum of squares of three consecutive integers.  I wanted to use $$(a+2)^2+(a-2)^2=2(a^2+4)$$ Also, $$a^2+(a+2)^2+(a+4)^2+1=3a^2+12a+21=3(a^2-1)+12(a+2)$$

Comment: @Flow Substitute $\ a\mapsto a+2\,$ in Lab's answer to get it into your terms. Then you'll have $\ (a+2)^2-1\,$ on the RHS, but it remains divisible by $4\ \ $

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to figure out how is 3a^2 +12a +21 = 3(a^2 - 1) +12(a+2)

Comment: @Flow You don't need to expand anything after you substitute $\,a\mapsto  a+2.\,$ On the RHS you get $\,3((a+2)^2-1)+12$ and we know from part 1 that $\, 4\mid (a+2)^2-1\,$ since $\,a+2\,$ is odd (by $\,a\,$ odd).